docker container cannot access host DNS
I have a DNS server on my DNS host but containers on this host cannot access this server.
I have Adguard DNS in a docker container running on host 192.168.1.2
The router advertises 192.168.1.2 + 9.9.9.9 as a DNS with dnsmasq
It is working fine on the whole network. On the docker host (192.168.1.2), DNS is setup properly and is working fine.
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.1.2
nameserver 9.9.9.9

But on containers the Adguard DNS is not working. This is an example on one container :
When I run nslookup www.google.com 192.168.1.2
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
When I run nslookup www.google.com it works but after 4 seconds. It means that it fails back to second DNS (9.9.9.9)
Same for nslookup www.google.com 127.0.0.11, it works after 4 seconds.
From this container, I can access the host using for example wget 192.168.10.120:9000
nslookup www.google.com adguard (with adguard beeing the name of the DNS container) works.
If I add server 192.168.1.2 as a DNS server to the docker container, it doesn't work.

it sounds like there is no route from the containers to this 192.168.1.0/24 network. It's certainly not clear from the question what network the host(s?) are connected to

the host is connected to 192.168.1.0/24
from a container I can access for example 192.168.1.2:9000

It seems that it can connect to port 53 of the host but I don't known why it cannot access the DNS server :(
nc -z  192.168.1.2 53
Connection to 192.168.1.2 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!
